# Detecting 502 responses in Nginx Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, load-balancing, https

I have the following setup - Nginx load balancer that receives https traffic and passes through to nodes. On each node there is a reverse proxy that handles https traffic and passes data to App1, App2 in plain text.

```
--> LB --> RP -> App1, App2
       `-> RP -> App1, App2
```

Now the issue is that if App1 is down on a node, load balancer doesn't detect that and is happily serving 502 back to the client. I guess it is because reverse proxy is still up and is encrypting the traffic and therefore load balancer simply passes through data. How can I inform load balancer that the App1 on node1 is down and go to the other node?

Simplified LB nginx.conf:

```
stream {
    map "$ssl_preread_server_name:$server_port" $namehttps {
        hostnames;
        some-address.io:8443 test_site;
    }

    upstream test_site {
        server 192.168.1.10;
        server 192.168.1.11
    }
    server {
        proxy_pass $namehttps;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

Reverse proxy nginx.conf acts as a standard reverse proxy terminating ssl traffic and passing un-encrypted traffic to an app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `stream` and should not be.

nginx has no visibility to the connection payload when using `stream` proxies. It has no way to even know that there is HTTP in there, nor does `stream` care anything about the payload.

You will need to use "a standard reverse proxy terminating ssl traffic".

Comment: I can't avoid using stream, as it is generic load balancer. Furthermore, I can't terminate ssl traffic on loadbalancer, as there is a requirement that no un-encrypted traffic goes over network (even if it is internal).

Comment: @RapolasK. Then you can't detect 502 responses. You will have to do something else. But why can't you re-encrypt the traffic?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you mean, you can use active health checks, which are basically periodic HTTP requests.

As per the NGINX documentation (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/), which I'm going to summarize here in case the page goes 404, you have to:

- define in the `server` portion of the configuration a `location /` (or similar path) section;
- include the `proxy_pass` and `health_check` directive in the location / (or similar) section;
- in the `http` `upstream` server group, define a shared memory by adding `zone backend 64k` (or similar value).

However, this doesn't work if you're using a `stream` block, because streams work at the TCP/UDP layer. The upstream must be contained in a `http` block, so you can benefit from the higher-layer features of the `http` module.